# In Akka.Net, how would a non-UI actor communicate data back to the UI thread?

Tags: f#, akka.net

The only references I can find involve configuring the actor to run ON the UI thread...? In F# you can (per Tomas Petricek) use the UI SynchronizationContext and the (SyncContext).Post command to fire an event that carries data from a long-running, background-threaded agent to the UI thread, and set up the UI to handle those events. How is this accomplished in Akka.net?

Comment: OK, so according to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28940122/akka-net-actors-in-sta , the answer is to setup an receiving actor that uses "akka.actor.synchronized-dispatcher" on the UI thread, and have any long-running background actors (that are most probably configured to use akka.actor.threadpool-dispatcher) communicate with it through messaging, and the UI-threaded actor handles the message, like updating a chart from data sent by a background actor....? thx